# Node.js, how do i take HTML form text input and direct it to a local file

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I am trying to take some very simple text input through a form and direct it to a .txt file. not getting much luck and am way out of my depth, any help appreciated.

I have tried a few different ways but atm i am trying to GET the input, turn this into json data and send directly to the file.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var passport = require('passport');
var passportLocal = require('passport-local');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator')


//routes setup
var index = require('./routes/index');
var homepage = require('./routes/homepage');
var login = require('./routes/login');
 var charitySignUp = require('./routes/charitySignUp');
var about = require('./routes/about');
var contactUs = require('./routes/contactUs');
var charityHomepage = require('./routes/charityHomepage');
var chat = require('./routes/newsFeed');
var ticket = require ('./routes/ticket');


var app = express();


require('./public/configure/passport');


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


//middleware
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(session({secret: 'mySecret', resave: false, saveUninitialized: 
false}));
//app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//routes + backend js file
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/homepage', homepage);
app.use('/charitySignUp', charitySignUp);
app.use('/about', about);
app.use('/contactUs', contactUs);
app.use('/charityHomepage', charityHomepage);
app.use('/chat', chat);
app.use('/ticket', ticket);


  / catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
// set locals, only providing error in development
res.locals.message = err.message;
res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

// render the error page
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error');


});


module.exports = app;
```

Ticket.js - backend code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');



router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
res.render('ticket');
});


router.get('/insert', function (req, res) {


var issue = req.query.issue;
var email = req.query.email;
fs.appendFile("my_file.txt", JSON.stringify(email + issue), function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('updated');
});
});


module.exports = router;
```

form in .EJS file.

```
 <form class="form-signin" action="/insert" method="get">
    <h2 class ="text" class="form-signin-heading">Ticket form</h2>



    <label class="sr-only"><b>email</b></label>
    <input type="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email you would like your response directed" name="email" required>

    <label class="sr-only"><b>Issue</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="type here" name="issue" required>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>



   </form>
```

Comment: Nothing leaps out as being wrong with that code. Can you be more detailed about the problem than "not getting much luck"? How does the actual behaviour differ from the desired behaviour? What have you done to debug it?

Comment: on submit whatever i type into the form is not sent to the .txt file. if i remove the json.stringify(email + issue) and replace it with a string then it works fine but obviously this is not much use to me! I have just noticed too that req.query.issue is telling me that there is an 'unresolved variable issue' with this.